# Computed properties on an item of dom-repeat template

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

If I have the following `dom-repeat` template:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{myFiles}}" as="file">
  <span>
    {{file.createDate}} <br/>
  </span>
</template>
```

and I would like to format `file.createDate`, is there a way to use [computed property](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers#computed-properties) to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you would need to use a [computed binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#annotated-computed) on the item (or in this case, its subproperty):

```
// template
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{_myFiles}}" as="file">
  <span>{{_formatDate(file.createDate)}}</span>
</template>

// script
Polymer({
  _formatDate: function(createDate) {
    return /* format createDate */;
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you could use a computed property (e.g., named `_myFiles`) on the `myFiles` array, which would process all the items before the `dom-repeat` iteration:

```
// template
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{_myFiles}}" as="file">
  <span>[[file.createDate]]</span>
</template>

// script
Polymer({
  properties: {
    myFiles: Array,
    _myFiles: {
      computed: '_preprocessFiles(myFiles)'
    }
  },
  _preprocessFiles: function(files) {
    return files.map(x => {
      x.createDate = /* format x.createDate */;
      return x;
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I had to define my computed property as such: 

          myFiles: {
            type: Array,
            computed: '_preprocessFiles(myFiles)',
            notify: true
          }